# signal.signal not working with threading, or another Why can't I use Ctrl-C to stop my Multi-threaded Python code?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading, sigterm

I have been banging my head against this all Labor Day long weekend. The code below does not stop with Ctrl-C. I must be doing something brain dead and can't see it anymore. Not only does it not stop, but I never get the signal handler message,
`"Interrupted by %d, shutting down"`

I hear terms like "blocked," but I don't know what they mean. Is my SIGTERM somehow "blocked"? I also do not understand the difference between killpill.wait and killpill.is_set(). But, that seems like a secondary problem. Since I never seem to catch the SIGTERM, the killpill method shouldn't matter.

I am using Python 3.8.5 on Windows 10, running in PowerShell.

```
import signal
import logging
import threading

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,
                    format='[%(levelname)s] (%(threadName)-10s) %(message)s')


def quit(signo, _frame):  # Graceful exit when we get ^C
    print("Interrupted by %d, shutting down" % signo)
    killpill.set()


def doit():
    try:
        while not(killpill.wait(1)):
            logging.debug( "starting ... " + str( killpill.is_set() ))
            time.sleep(1)
            logging.debug( "working ... " + str( killpill.is_set()) )
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        logging.debug("KeyboardInterrupt stopping mouse_info")

        
def main():
    global killpill
    killpill = threading.Event()
    t1=threading.Thread(name='t1',target=doit)
    t1.daemon=True
    t1.start()
    t1.join()
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)


if (__name__ == '__main__'):
    for sig in ('TERM', 'INT', 'BREAK', 'ABRT'):
        signal.signal(getattr(signal, 'SIG'+sig), quit)
    main()
```

Any helpful insight would be greatly appreciated. The output is

```
[DEBUG] (t1        ) working ... False
[DEBUG] (t1        ) starting ... False
[DEBUG] (t1        ) working ... False
[DEBUG] (t1        ) starting ... False
```

Comment: I tried one more thing before going to sleep based on other references. I made the following changes:
'killpill.wait(1)' became 'killpill.is_set()'
and 
in the main() `while True` loop, I added 
`t1.join(10) \ if not(t1.is_alive()): \break`
However, I have no clue why these workedwhen the original did not.

Comment: you check `KeyboardInterrupt` in threads but they don't have access to keyboard. I would use it in main thread.